# Removing Carrierwave previously uploaded file messes up new file processing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

I'm using https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave with AWS3 to upload my app file to Amazon. I've got an Employee model with an image column (think of it as the employee profile picture) which has an uploader mounted to it:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base

  mount_uploader :image, ProfileImageUploader

  ...

end
```

Whenever an employee updates its profile picture, I want the previous one to be deleted. In order to do this, I've got the following :after_update callback in my Employee model:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base

  ...

  after_update :remove_changed_image, :if => 'self.image_changed?'

  def remove_changed_image
    self.image_was.remove!
  end

end
```

This successfully deletes the previous file. But I'm also processing the pictures that get uploaded. In my Uploder I have the following:

```
class ProfileImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_limit => [300, 300]
  end

  ...

end
```

The problem is that the new files are not being processed at all. Only one version, the unprocessed one, gets uploaded, whereas if I don't remove the previous image, then all works as it should (many versions are uploaded).

Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `after_update` callback. It is called after the object is saved, thus deleting the newly attached file. You need to call `@employee.remove_image` before saving the object.